# Evitar ingresar un dato ya registrado en dataGridView c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Un gran saludo a todos. Espero que me puedan ayudar. Ya eh buscado en varias partes pero no eh encontrado lo que necesito. Lo único que necesito :( es que al ingresar por ejemplo pedro y si este ya esta en mi datagridview no lo agregue y me arroje un mensaje de que ya esta ingresado.
Ingreso los datos a través de un texbox con dataGridView1.Rows.Add solo necesito validar una sola columna

Espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: Cuando hagas alguna pregunta es indispensable que Agregues un fragmento de código que lo que tienes para que se te pueda ayudar de la mejor manera. En este caso te doy el método pero como no pones como tienes el código en tu botton no podemos ayudarte demasiado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de Agregar a "Pedro" Validalo recorriendo tu DGV de esta manera:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in DGV.Rows)
{
   foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in Row.Cells)
   {
      string Valor = Convert.ToString(cell.Value);
      if (Valor.Contains(this.Texboxt.Text))
      {
           //Pedro Existe en el DGV
      }
   }
}
```

Lo que hace este código es buscar en todo el **DataGridView** la Palabra o la cadena de texto que hayas puesto en tu Textbox.

Comment: muchas gracias Jesus Vazquez me ayudo tu código. Me disculpo por no subir el código completo, pero en mi apuro simplemente subí la pregunta